# How to put quotation marks (') in the content of a vim macro?

Tags: vimrc, macro

I use `:%s/'/"/g`
to replace all single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` in a plain-text file

but when I want to put this command in a vim macro in .vimrc

`let @r=':%s/'/"/g'`

opening vim will give me this error

> E114: Missing quote: "/g'
>
> E15: Invalid expression: ':%s/'/"/g'
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I've tried not including the surrounding single-quotes
`let @r=:%s/'/"/g`

it still gives me a similar error.

how do I include commands with single-quotes in a vim macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you add another single quote to escape your single quote inside your vim macro

```
let @r=':%s/''/"/g'
```

from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Macros

> if your register must itself contain single quote characters, you use
> a second single-quote character to escape it.
>
> For example, if you want
> your register to contain "Vim's quote handling is a little tricky" you
> would type :let @a='"Vim''s quote handling is a little tricky"'