# Escape for double quotes not working

Tags: escape

I'm trying to search for quotation mark, but it seems it doesn't work:

```
\v^\s"\zs\"+
```

is what i tried. Though I'm well aware it need to be escaped...I tried:

```
\v^\s""\zs\""+
```

given what was said [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24433/30351), though I'm guessing this method only work for single quotes.

And lastly tried this:

```
\v^\s\"\zs\\"+
```

where i try to escape it with a `\`. (afaik).

Any way to escape double quotes here?

Comment: Do you mean to search for `\v^\s*\zs"+` ? That will match one or more `"` after optional whitespace at the beginning of a line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you adapted this from the regex in the previous question matching `*`s.

But `*` is a metacharacter to match 0 or more of the previous token. That means:

1. You should still use `*` (not `"`) after `\s` to match optional whitespace at the beginning of the line.
2. You shouldn't use a backslash to escape the `"`, since `"` is not a metacharacter. It was needed for `*` to match a literal `*`, but it's not needed for `"`. (It still works if you escape it, but you don't need it.)

This regex should work: `\v^\s*\zs"+`